# Stream Zipping A "Folder" Of S3 Files And Store The Compressed File To Another S3 Location

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to compress a folder (prefix) of files in S3 which is large than 200GB in total. I found that [smart_open](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open#how) is a quite promising package for this, but I still need more guidance on how to use it after reading the "[How To](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open#how)" wiki.

#### Details of my problem:

I have a folder of S3 files like:

```
--S3_Bucket_1/file_folder
  -- folder1/file1.parquet
  -- folder2/file2.parquet
  -- text_file1.txt
  -- jar_file1.jar
...
```

I want to compress all files in `file_folder` (>200GB) in streaming manner, and save the compressed file to another S3 location, i.e., `s3://bucket2/123/output.gz`

I have found that the functionalities provided by [smart_open](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open#how) are quite close to what I need. Using the code below I was able to successfully compress all files under `file_folder` to a **single file** with in `output.gz`:

```py
import os
import boto3
import smart_open
from io import RawIOBase
from smart_open import s3

session = boto3.Session()
source_bucket_name = "S3_Bucket_1" # the source bucket contains the file I want to compress
bucket = session.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket_name)
prefix = "file_folder" # s3 prefix for the files under a "folder"

output_path = "s3://bucket2/123/output.gz" # output where I want to save the compressed files

with smart_open.open(output_path, 'wb') as fout:
    for key, content in s3.iter_bucket(source_bucket_name, prefix = prefix):
        fout.write(content)
```

However, this won't work since all files are mixed into a single file within the compressed file. I want to maintain the original file structure.

I also tried to compress the files using `ZipFile` in Python:

```
source_bucket_name = "S3_Bucket_1" # the source bucket contains the file I want to compress
prefix = "file_folder" # s3 prefix for the files under a "folder"
output_path = "s3://bucket2/123/output.gz" # output where I want to save the compressed files

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
    tp = {'writebuffer': tmp}
    with open(s3_zip_path, 'wb', transport_params=tp) as fout:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(fout, 'w') as zipper:
            for key, content in s3.iter_bucket(source_bucket_name, prefix = prefix):
                zipper.writestr(key, content)
```

This gives me error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-e61f4a7d1257> in <module>
     19         with zipfile.ZipFile(fout, 'w') as zipper:
     20             for key, content in s3.iter_bucket(source_bucket_name, prefix = prefix):
---> 21                 zipper.writestr(key, content)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py in writestr(self, zinfo_or_arcname, data, compress_type, compresslevel)
   1815         with self._lock:
   1816             with self.open(zinfo, mode='w') as dest:
-> 1817                 dest.write(data)
   1818 
   1819     def __del__(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py in close(self)
   1178                 # Preserve current position in file
   1179                 self._zipfile.start_dir = self._fileobj.tell()
-> 1180                 self._fileobj.seek(self._zinfo.header_offset)
   1181                 self._fileobj.write(self._zinfo.FileHeader(self._zip64))
   1182                 self._fileobj.seek(self._zipfile.start_dir)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/gzip.py in seek(self, offset, whence)
    374                     raise ValueError('Seek from end not supported')
    375             if offset < self.offset:
--> 376                 raise OSError('Negative seek in write mode')
    377             count = offset - self.offset
    378             chunk = b'\0' * 1024

OSError: Negative seek in write mode
```

Anyone has done similar thing such as zipping files in streaming mode in Python?

Comment: It seems you want one input object to result in one (compressed) output object. Therefore, loop through the objects and use a different `output_path` for each object, in the destination bucket (by swapping the order of the `with` and `for` lines). This should be done from an Amazon EC2 instance to avoid Data Transfer costs (and make it faster).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I need N uncompressed files to be in one compressed file. Your suggested solution would result to multiple .gz files right? How should I compress them into one in this case?

Comment: Oh! When you said "this won't work since all files are mixed into a single file within the compressed file. I want to maintain the original file structure", I assumed you wanted single files only. So, you're actually asking for a single zip but with the hierarchy preserved. It looks like that isn't supported with `smart_open()`: [Multiple files inside target zip file · Issue #311 · RaRe-Technologies/smart_open · GitHub](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open/issues/311)